# Cause of the AFM Error in CA Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am getting the Invalid AFM error while running a command in CA Job Automation Scheduler. Please let me know what is the cause of this error and how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: As it stands, your question is unclear and too broad, can you please provide sufficient information such that responders can attempt to provide support or solutions. As you have indicated an Automated Framework Message Error, you should both include the content of that error in your question along with the Windows batch file you have used. In the meantime, take a look at [this](https://docops.ca.com/ca-workload-automation-system-agent/11-3/en/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-tips/trace-an-automated-framework-message) to see if it at least helps you to narrow your problem area.

Comment: Hi @Compo, I dont get any error logs. The status was displayed as Invalid AFM and the job went to SUBERROR State.

Comment: In summary, you are getting an error which you cannot narrow down and all the information we have is what is written by you in your question. So fully read the question and please ask yourself how you expect us to provide cause and fix?